# Import Remote Source Files in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, curl

I have a file in my VM called `color.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Goal    : include all color
# Run     : curl 45.55.88.57/code/color.sh  | bash

# grap user input first argument
# ------------------------------

#================================
#            Colors             =
#================================

declare -A colors

# Reset
colors[Color_Off]='\033[0m'       # Text Reset

# Regular Colors
colors[Black]='\033[0;30m'        # Black
colors[Red]='\033[0;31m'          # Red
colors[Green]='\033[0;32m'        # Green
colors[Yellow]='\033[0;33m'       # Yellow
colors[Blue]='\033[0;34m'         # Blue
colors[Purple]='\033[0;35m'       # Purple
colors[Cyan]='\033[0;36m'         # Cyan
colors[White]='\033[0;37m'        # White

# Bold
colors[BBlack]='\033[1;30m'       # Black
colors[BRed]='\033[1;31m'         # Red
colors[BGreen]='\033[1;32m'       # Green
colors[BYellow]='\033[1;33m'      # Yellow
colors[BBlue]='\033[1;34m'        # Blue
colors[BPurple]='\033[1;35m'      # Purple
colors[BCyan]='\033[1;36m'        # Cyan
colors[BWhite]='\033[1;37m'       # White

# Underline
colors[UBlack]='\033[4;30m'       # Black
colors[URed]='\033[4;31m'         # Red
colors[UGreen]='\033[4;32m'       # Green
colors[UYellow]='\033[4;33m'      # Yellow
colors[UBlue]='\033[4;34m'        # Blue
colors[UPurple]='\033[4;35m'      # Purple
colors[UCyan]='\033[4;36m'        # Cyan
colors[UWhite]='\033[4;37m'       # White

# Background
colors[On_Black]='\033[40m'       # Black
colors[On_Red]='\033[41m'         # Red
colors[On_Green]='\033[42m'       # Green
colors[On_Yellow]='\033[43m'      # Yellow
colors[On_Blue]='\033[44m'        # Blue
colors[On_Purple]='\033[45m'      # Purple
colors[On_Cyan]='\033[46m'        # Cyan
colors[On_White]='\033[47m'       # White

# High Intensity
colors[IBlack]='\033[0;90m'       # Black
colors[IRed]='\033[0;91m'         # Red
colors[IGreen]='\033[0;92m'       # Green
colors[IYellow]='\033[0;93m'      # Yellow
colors[IBlue]='\033[0;94m'        # Blue
colors[IPurple]='\033[0;95m'      # Purple
colors[ICyan]='\033[0;96m'        # Cyan
colors[IWhite]='\033[0;97m'       # White

# Bold High Intensity
colors[BIBlack]='\033[1;90m'      # Black
colors[BIRed]='\033[1;91m'        # Red
colors[BIGreen]='\033[1;92m'      # Green
colors[BIYellow]='\033[1;93m'     # Yellow
colors[BIBlue]='\033[1;94m'       # Blue
colors[BIPurple]='\033[1;95m'     # Purple
colors[BICyan]='\033[1;96m'       # Cyan
colors[BIWhite]='\033[1;97m'      # White

# High Intensity backgrounds
colors[On_IBlack]='\033[0;100m'   # Black
colors[On_IRed]='\033[0;101m'     # Red
colors[On_IGreen]='\033[0;102m'   # Green
colors[On_IYellow]='\033[0;103m'  # Yellow
colors[On_IBlue]='\033[0;104m'    # Blue
colors[On_IPurple]='\033[0;105m'  # Purple
colors[On_ICyan]='\033[0;106m'    # Cyan
colors[On_IWhite]='\033[0;107m'   # White
```

I want to import it into my other shell scripts. I'm not sure how to achieve that.

I've tried calling it on other script:

`bashrc.sh`

```
curl 45.55.88.57/code/color.sh | source

color=${colors[$input_color]}
white=${colors[White]}

export PS1='$white┌──[$color\u$white@$color\h$white]──$white[$color\w$white] \n└── $white'
```

It doesn't work.

Any hints for me?

Comment: Do you get an error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an easier way to reproduce your problem:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'var=42' | source
echo "The variable is $var"
```

When executed:

```
$ ./foo
./foo: line 2: source: filename argument required
source: usage: source filename [arguments]
The variable is
```

There are two problems:

1. `source` doesn't read from stdin
2. Piping to `source` will create a subshell, restricting any changes

On Bash 4, you can solve both by using Process Substitution:

```
source <(curl 45.55.88.57/code/color.sh)
```

Bash 3 (as found on MacOS) has a bug preventing this, but you can use `eval` instead. This also works on Bash4:

```
eval "$(curl 45.55.88.57/code/color.sh)"
```